# Saving scrollOffset to UITableView datasource in didEndDisplayingCell not dequeuing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView with a custom cell defined, and in each custom cell, is a UICollectionView. I'm populating the data from a top-level array of data objects, with each containing an inner array of data objects for the collection view. In JSON, this looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "collectionViewData": [
            {
                "name": "subobject1"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject2"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject3"
            }
        ],
        "name": "object1"
    },
    {
        "collectionViewData": [
            {
                "name": "subobject1"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject2"
            }
        ],
        "name": "object2"
    },
    {
        "collectionViewData": [
            {
                "name": "subobject1"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject2"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject3"
            },
            {
                "name": "subobject4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "object3"
    }
]
```

This works fine, and behaves as expected. What I'm trying to do now is save the `contentOffset` on `didEndDisplayingCell` into my datasource so that the next time the tableview cell is redrawn, the scroll location is restored.

This seems to work just fine - except something is goofing in the dequeuing mechanism because every other cell is loading the previously dequeued cell's offset - e.g:

- 0 = offset of {170, 0}
- 1 = offset of {0, 0}
- 2 then loads with 0's
  offset of {170, 0}

What's going wrong? Why am I seeing this behavior and how do I fix it?

```
- (MyTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";

    MyTableViewCell *row = (MyTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (row == nil)
    {
        row = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSInteger idx = (indexPath.row % [MUTABLE_DATASOURCE_ARRAY count]);
    MyCustomCollectionObjectContainer *collectionViewObjectContainer = [MUTABLE_DATASOURCE_ARRAY objectAtIndex:idx];

    [row.collectionView setContentOffset:collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset animated:NO];
    DDLogDebug(@"ROW %ld %@: cellForRow actual: %@, want: %@", idx, collectionViewObjectContainer.collectionName, NSStringFromCGPoint(row.collectionView.contentOffset), NSStringFromCGPoint(collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset));
    row.collectionName = collectionViewObjectContainer.collectionName;
    row.collectionViewObjectContainer = collectionViewObjectContainer.innerDataArray;
    row.labelcollectionViewObjectContainer.text = [collectionViewObjectContainer.collectionName uppercaseString];
    [row.labelcollectionViewObjectContainer setNeedsDisplay];

    return row;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(MyTableViewCell *)row forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger idx = (indexPath.row % [MUTABLE_DATASOURCE_ARRAY count]);
    MyCustomCollectionObjectContainer *collectionViewObjectContainer = [MUTABLE_DATASOURCE_ARRAY objectAtIndex:idx];
    collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset = row.collectionView.contentOffset;
    MUTABLE_DATASOURCE_ARRAY[idx] = collectionViewObjectContainer;
    DDLogDebug(@"ROW %ld %@: didEndDisplayingCell set: %@", idx, collectionViewObjectContainer.collectionName, NSStringFromCGPoint(collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset));
}
```

**Update:** In this log output, sometimes the "actual" is wrong, and the "want" is correct, even though in the previous line, I'm clearly setting the content offset. Is there a quick and dirty way to force the content offset to take?

```
[row.collectionView setContentOffset:collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset animated:NO];
DDLogDebug(@"ROW %ld %@: cellForRow actual: %@, want: %@", idx, collectionViewObjectContainer.collectionName, NSStringFromCGPoint(row.collectionView.contentOffset), NSStringFromCGPoint(collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset));
```

Further to this, I forgot (slap!) that it wasn't working at all in the first place, so I overrode `setContentOffset` in my collection view subclass:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

Doh! That doesn't do ANYTHING. But if I remove it, now I'm plagued with my original problem in that when the new table view cell is initialized, the inner collection view does NOT scroll to the desired content offset even though the logging correctly logs out the content offset each time now. Maybe I need to call something other than `setContentOffset` altogether?

Comment: You might need to create a dictionary of cell offsets to ensure you obtain the correct offset for each row? I do this to retain a cell's checked state. Have you considered this?

Comment: I'm doing that - it's storing it correctly in the NSObject subclass that I use for my datasource. If I NSLog the datasource out, the correct array index is being updated.

Comment: I recall suffering a similar problem I'll have a look tonight, recall it had something to do with where I was presenting code in the controller lifecycle.

Comment: @andrewbuilder see update - looks like `setContentOffset` isn't always taking effect?

Answer (score 1):

Super messed up, but it seems to work just fine when I put a 0.1s delay before calling `setContentOffset`:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [row.collectionView setContentOffset: collectionViewObjectContainer.lastContentOffset animated:NO];
});
```

Seems like this is more of a hack than a solution, but it is indeed working.

**Update:**

Tragic end to what could have been a cool problem to solve. Turns out I was setting the content offset in my `UITableViewCell` subclass's `awakeFromNib` to CGPointZero. Setting it to my saved content offset fixed it.

Comment: These hacks are a bad idea, because on an iOS update they might stop working.... Just saying.

Comment: @Lefteris totally agree. Feels really wrong. I'm happy to have a better answer left here 

Comment: You are giving conflicting information though, because on your original post you where saying that the contentOffset was not correctly stored. Here you only set it via a timer, which means the contentOffset is correctly stored, but it's not scrolling the collectionView, unless you set a timeout. This makes sense as the collectionView is probably still being drawn by the UIKit when you set the contentOffset, which causes it not to do anything. I'd subclass the collectionView and would set the contentOffset in the `didMoveToWindow` delegate

Comment: Slight misunderstanding - it was always being stored correctly, but it was never being set correctly. Originally I had overridden setContentOffset, and the dequeue goofiness was a side effect. Removing that override, it didn't set at all until I added the timer. I like your idea about didMoveToWindow - I'll give that a shot.

Comment: `didMoveToWindow` isn't even being called, because the containing table cell is already initialized (and I'm using Storyboards). I tried `awakeFromNib` too, and `init`, `initWithFrame` and they're not called. The only way I could see doing it that way is to set the collectionView to nil each time, but then that adds some crazy lag in the scrolling. I also tried just setting a property `expectedContentOffset` and returning that in `-(CGPoint)contentOffset:` -- but it totally goofed.

Comment: Hmmm, you might have to subclass the UITableViewCell and do this in the prepareForReuse delegate method

Comment: Oh my. Now I feel like an idiot. `[_collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];` was already IN my subclass of UITableViewCell:awakeFromNib. NO WONDER. Sigh.